# Problems with Foundation system clock precision in OSX Mavericks 13F34?

Tags: macos, time, timer, osx-mavericks

I have been noticing all kinds of weird timing with my music in Logic Pro X, and I am seeing major fluctuations in the nanoseconds from my system's clock. I decided to create a for loop and compare differentials and I noticed something really strange which I had originally thought was a software issue?
Steps to Reproduce:

```
>>> from Foundation import *
>>> for i in range(1,32):
...     now = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime()
...     delta = now - prev
...     prev = now
...     print str(now) + ", delta=" + str(delta)
...     time.sleep(1)
... 
13021.1874697, delta=13021.1874697
13022.1882823, delta=1.00081255
13023.1883955, delta=1.000113186
13024.1894656, delta=1.001070095
13025.1896117, delta=1.000146088
13026.1906813, delta=1.001069595
13027.1917512, delta=1.001069892
13028.1929504, delta=1.001199214
13029.1941442, delta=1.001193793
13030.1953468, delta=1.001202675
13031.196421, delta=1.001074142
13032.1975382, delta=1.00111725
13033.1982311, delta=1.000692907
13034.1984295, delta=1.000198325
13035.1986785, delta=1.000248999
13036.1990507, delta=1.000372273
13037.1993152, delta=1.000264465
13038.1996434, delta=1.000328253
13039.2000955, delta=1.000452101
13040.2011615, delta=1.001065969
13041.2021225, delta=1.000960959
13042.2031759, delta=1.001053454
13043.2037789, delta=1.000602964
13044.2044619, delta=1.000683005
13045.2048414, delta=1.00037947
13046.206041, delta=1.00119968
13047.2065136, delta=1.000472508
13048.2066852, delta=1.000171626
13049.2077582, delta=1.001073025
13050.2087482, delta=1.000990021
13051.2090188, delta=1.000270521
>>>
```

Comment: Basically, if you notice the differential on each second increment, it is changing from 1 millisecond down to 146 microseconds in difference, and very inconsistently???

Comment: Here is what I am seeing for time settings in sysctl... Was this set manually??! http://pastebin.com/bzjyad4z

Answer (score 0):

sleep() is not suitable for timing a media stream. `man -S3 sleep` says "System activity may lengthen the sleep by an indeterminate amount." Media streams should be clocked by the playback or source device, usually with callbacks from the device driver. Even then the intervals can vary slightly.